# Como adicionar um arquivo a uma ChangeList

Tags: c#

Quero adicionar  arquivos a changelist "ignore-on-commit". 
Tenho esse código, que executa, e não da erro. (Mas também não funciona :v)

```
using(SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
   string sSoluctionDir = args[1].Remove(0, 1);
   var pes = Directory.GetFiles(sSoluctionDir, "AssemblyInfo.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
   for (int i = 0; i < pes.Length; i++)
   {
   SvnAddToChangeListArgs a = new SvnAddToChangeListArgs();
   client.AddToChangeList(pes[i], "ignore-on-commit", a);
   }

}
```